# wait() and notify() method , always IllegalMonitorStateException is happen and tell me current Thread is not Owner Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
package pkg_1;

public class ExpOnWaitMethod extends Thread {

    static Double x = new Double(20);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExpOnWaitMethod T1 = new ExpOnWaitMethod();
        ExpOnWaitMethod T2 = new ExpOnWaitMethod();

        T1.start();

        T2.start();

    }

    public void run() {

        Mag mag = new Mag();

        synchronized (x) {

            try {
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    mag.nop(Thread.currentThread());
                    x = i * 2.0;

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}

class Mag {
    char ccc = 'A';

    public void nop(Thread thr) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.print(ccc + " ");
        ccc++;

        if (thr.getState().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("runnable"))
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
        //thr.notify();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to hold the lock on the object you want to `wait` on (you can only call it within a `synchronized` block).

Also, calling `wait` on a `Thread` is very unusual and probably not what you want.

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but could you be confusing `wait` with `sleep`?

If you want to wait for another thread to finish, that would be `anotherThread.join()`.

Comment: I agree calling wait on a thread monitor is as strange as calling a wait on a java.util.concurrent.Condition monitor :)

Comment: we keep crossing paths.  Cheerio!

Answer (score 5):

Before you call `wait` on an object, you must acquire that object's lock:

```
synchronized(obj)
{
    obj.wait();
}
```

Your code is calling `wait` on a `Thread` object without acquiring the lock first.

I assume this is just a simplified test case to show your problem, but note that you probably want to be calling `wait` on an object that is accessible from all threads, not on the `Thread` objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Someone should cite the API contract for [`java.lang.Object.wait()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29), which explains this directly.  If a method raises an exception, read the documentation.

When in doubt, read the contract.  (Bill McNeal on NewsRadio always kept his in his jacket pocket, a good metaphor for the JavaDoc API.. see "Crazy Prepared" under [NewsRadio](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NewsRadio) and ponder the imponderable.)